# Using JLabel with libgdx's Pixmap

Tags: java, jlabel, libgdx

I was wondering if you anybody knows an easy way to paint a `JLabel` in a libgdx's `Pixmap`, instead of using a `BufferedImage`.

I have seen that libgdx uses JLabel in some tools, but I haven't seen any painting procedure, so I took the lazy way of asking before I keep looking. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can render to a BufferedImage and then copy out the bytes into a buffer which you can use to create a Pixmap. See [here](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/extensions/gdx-tools/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tools/hiero/unicodefont/GlyphPage.java#137). This won't be fast though, and only works on the desktop.